# How to Rewrite URL via Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to open my site's links without **?** in it.

for example my website is randomly generating links like

```
https://example.com/quiz/?cndyZXQ==MTAw
```

I want to open links as

```
https://example.com/quiz/cndyZXQ==MTAw
```

or

```
https://example.com/myquiz/cndyZXQ==MTAw
```

Is it possible via htaccess? then how?
I have already tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2,2})/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ quiz/?$1 [QSA]
```

seems didn't worked, anyone help me out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^quiz/$ /myquiz/%1 [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Comment: For reflecting new changes you need to remove the HTTP caches or you can try "Guest" window of chrome.

Comment: using this code where this https://example.com/quiz/?cndyZXQ==MTAw url redirects?

Answer (score 0):

U could try this.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ $1%1? [R,L]